# Python Получить данные словаря если есть его имя как строка

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict, словарь

Например у меня есть:

```py
client1={"Name":"Vladimir","Surname":"Ivanovich","age":40}
client2={"Name":"Sergey","Surname":"Vitaliev","age":23}
info="client1"
```

Как теперь получить словарь client1 из переменной info?(То есть если-бы info="client2", то тогда он выводил словарь client2, а если info="client1", то выводить client1)
Помогите пожалуйста :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией `globals()`. Она возвращает все глобальные переменные и их значение в виде словаря

Выглядеть это будет так: `print(globals()[info])`

Answer (score 5):

Лучше так не делать. Можно просто пололожить ваши словари в ещё один словарь, и обращаться к ним по ключу:

```
clients = {
    "client1": {"Name":"Vladimir","Surname":"Ivanovich","age":40},
    "client2": {"Name":"Sergey","Surname":"Vitaliev","age":23},
}

info="client1"

print(clients[info])
```